# LINQ search Product Index

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, search-engine

I have a `List<Product>` contains properties of Bikes (`Name`, `ProductName`, `Color`, `List` `Price`). I'm struggling to figure out how to write a search function using LINQ. I'd like to find a name of `Bike`. Any suggest will be help me some ways.

Comment: what are you trying to find exactly?

Comment: I'd like to find a name of Bike @MoslemBenDhaou

Comment: Do you mean: find Bike by name?

Comment: Exactly what am I want to find!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that your name is taken from a variable called nameToSearch.

This is if you want to get the Product.

```
string nameToSearch = "BikeName";
List<Product> list = bikes.Where(x => x.Name == nameToSearch).ToList();
```

Comment: +1 that is a good one, but that is more a lambda expression than LINQ

Comment: Yeah, but as you know, Where method and ToList is in the Linq namespace. But yesh, in some point, you are right ;) Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have the following `Product` class:

```
public class Product
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String ProductName { get; set; }
    public String Color { get; set; }
    public String List { get; set; }
    public String Price { get; set; }
}
```

You also mentioned you have your data in a `List<Product>`. I will give a demo name for it:

```
List<Product> myProductList = GetProductList();
// Where GetProductList() will create a new List<Product> and populate it.

String bikeNameFilter = GetNameFilter();
// You can chnage this by the string you want for filtering.
```

You can use the following to get your data:

```
List<Product> myFilteredProductList = (from p in myProductList
                                       where p.Name = bikeNameFilter
                                       select p;
                                      ).ToList()
```

Obviously you can change the filter you want to use to another property of your product. Finally to get the actual name, you can loop through the list you just got:

```
foreach (var p in myFilteredProductList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(p.ProductName);
    // Use this value wherever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at a nuget package I have created

### http://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions

This will enable the following (and more) which will return results where the search term appears in **any** of the properties specified

```
var result = products.Search("searchTerm", p => p.Name, p => p.ProductName);
```

Performing a search against all `string` properties can be done as follows:

```
var result = products.Search("searchTerm");
```

Alternatively, you can perform an `AND` search where the search term exists in a set of properties as follows:

```
string searchTerm = "searchTerm";
var result = products.Search(searchTerm, p => p.Name) 
                     .Search(searchTerm, p => p.ProductName);
```

For more information take a look at the **[projects GitHub page](https://github.com/ninjanye/SearchExtensions)** or my **[blog posts](http://jnye.co/posts/tagged/search-extensions)**

---

**UPDATE**: don't forget the `using` directive...

```
using NinjaNye.SearchExtensions
```